# how to play live stream video in android browser?

Tags: android, html, live-streaming, android-browser

I am looking for an app like live steaming in android. i got a solution for this using Ip camera app in android.It is working fine in desktop's using the flv player. but in android browser it doesn't work. i want to play the live streaming video in any browser like android mobile browser or any computer browser. After my research i got a conclusion that html5 will play in any browser instead of flv. can any one suggest me regarding how the html5 can use in live steaming a video.

Please help with example code or any suitable links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

An HTML5 live streaming solution that works in *every* mobile browser unfortunately doesn't exist.

A browser claiming to support HTML5 video additionally has to support the used

- Codecs: Some support [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC), other support VP8 ([WebM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM)), a few support both.
- Streaming formats: Live video can't be streamed as a progressive HTTP download (at least not without some hacks of the common container formats like [.mp4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) (used primarily for H.264, and not to be confused with the [MPEG-4 video codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2)) or MKV (WebM is basically VP8 video in a MKV container).

Your best bet right now would probably be [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) - it's not exactly part of HTML5, but it is supported by Android, iOS and probably other mobile operating systems.

As a fallback for older devices, you could support [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) streaming, which is more widely supported on non-smartphones and older Android devices, but has the disadvantage of using the UDP-based RTP protocol instead of standard HTTP, which is more likely to pass through corporate firewalls and scales better with regards to content delivery networks, HTTP caches and the like.

Comment: Any starting points as to how to stream videos over RTSP from a nodejs server provided I have the ffmpeg already configured.

Answer (score 0):

You You can refer to below URLs,

http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

Comment: Thanks man.but it is not i required.what i need is,by using the ip address of mobile where my app is running. with that we can live stream that to any browser.

Comment: by using this http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/ link i developed the this app. but it is not working in android mobile browser.

Comment: because this app is supporting flv player.but the android device browser not having inbuilt plugins.I need, how to play this streaming with html5, because all browsers having html5 plugins

Comment: sorry, i think i cant help you on this matter.